# Fetch Data and check if has "Next Page" in One Query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, pagination

Is there any way to check if any rows left for the next LIMIT query (for showing Next Page link)?
I don't want COUNT(), extra SELECT, etc
I use Limit a,b for getting each pages's posts.

Thanks!

Comment: Check the total number of rows with `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Comment: @MathieuImbert and then? check last fetched row's id whit this?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `LIMIT N+1` in your query (where N is the actual limit). If the query returns N+1 rows, there are further pages; otherwise, you're on the last page. Of course this will require adjustments in other parts of your code, to omit the last row from the results displayed.

Comment: Thanks, the only negative point is the extra logic I should add for getting maximum N rows out of the N+1 that this query returns.